# Android switch text button?

Tags: android

I am developping an app that has some quotes but I am unable to have next/previous buttons to navigate between the quotes like in the attached image ??
can anybody help ?

http://img.technospot.net/Free-Android-app-Success-Quotes.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only that that's changing is the quote, just have the next and previous buttons change the text on click to the next quote in the cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are genarating randoms numbers to show the quotes randomly. Just save the position of the quotes(are they stored in an `array`?) and save them in an Integers List every time the user clicks next.

```
 List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

So if the user wants to go back just get the previous number which was shown by accessing the list with :

```
intList.get(intList.size()-1);
```

You should provide more informations next time and be as precise as you can.